# Error when importing image dynamically: "Error: Cannot find module './asset/<imageName>.jpg'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am currently trying to load local images based on the path given by JSON data. The data is passed in to my component as props.
Since the component is dynamically created based on the JSON data, I can't import the images. So I tried to "require" them, but I get an error saying,

**"Error: Cannot find module './asset/.jpg' "**

The image loads just fine if I manually import them, so I believe the path is formatted correctly.

Why am I getting error? How do I fix it?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Cell (props){

    return (
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th><img src= {require(props.image)} /></th>
        <th><div className = "name">{props.name}</div></th>
        <th>
            <a className = "upVote"></a>
            <a className = "downVote"></a>
        </th>
        <th className = "count">{props.count}</th>
    </tr>
    );
}

export default Cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is in `public` folder then you can directly write:

```
<img src={props.image} />
```

OR

```
<img src="abc.png" />
```

There is no need to use `require` for it.

You can also import image like this if images and component is in same directory:

```
import abc from "./abc.jpeg";

<img src={abc} />
```

OR

```
<img src={require("./abc.jpeg")} />
```

Comment: My image is currently not in public folder. It is in src. Is there a benefit of placing it in the public folder?

Comment: It's on you if you want to use those images as static assets after build process then you can put it on `public` or `public/images` directory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I moved my asset to public folder and I dont get the error anymore. However, the image is not showing up.

Comment: @Joshua Can you tell me about the error. btw I've updated the answer above.

Comment: I dont get any errors. Instead the image just doesn't load - https://imgur.com/a/zL3WC6H. Maybe the path is wrong. My path is : "../public/asset/<imageName>.jpg"

Comment: You can also check your browser's URL if it given path is working or not `localhost:3000/asset/<imageName.jpg>`